# get date from varchar stored date format for friends birthday

Tags: mysql

I want to get the date from `varchar` stored date (eg `12-21-1990`). I can use php `explode` to get the current date, but I wanted to get it through mysql. I am using a query like this:

```
$count=mysql_query("SELECT u.fname, u.lname, u.profile_pic, u.uid, u.bday, f.uid, f.friend_id, f.status FROM friend_list f, users_profile u WHERE f.uid = '$id' AND f.status = '1' AND u.uid = f.friend_id ");
```

The above query gets me users friends with all details, but I wanted to only get friends deatails whose birthday is today. How can I do this?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [**red box**](http://php.net/mysql-connect)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, try [this article](http://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing). If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: thank you @MihaiIorga for informing me about this . I really didnt knew this ill change it

Comment: @ParamVeer: Is your problem resolved ? It is good practice to accept the helpful answer.

Comment: @HardikMishra yes my problem was solved way long back and i posted the correct answer too . and i accepted it so that it could help further someone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello just found the solution and wanted to share it so that it could help someone .

```
SELECT u.fname, u.lname, u.profile_pic, u.uid, u.bday, f.uid, f.friend_id, f.status FROM 
    friend_list f, users_profile u WHERE f.uid = '3' AND f.status = '1' AND u.uid = f.friend_id 
      and    DAY(STR_TO_DATE(u.bday, '%m-%d-%y')) = DAY(CURDATE()) AND
    MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(u.bday, '%m-%d-%y')) = MONTH(CURDATE())
```

Answer (score 2):

you can get today's date with php date function , assign it to a variable and check the u.bday against it.
like so :

```
$count=$today = date("m-d-Y");

mysql_query("SELECT u.fname, u.lname, u.profile_pic, u.uid, u.bday, f.uid, f.friend_id, f.status FROM friend_list f, users_profile u WHERE f.uid = '$id' AND f.status = '1' AND u.uid = f.friend_id AND u.bday = $today");
```

Comment: how can i just compare the month and date not the year?

Answer (score 0):

I would change the bday column data type to `DATE` and use `CUREDATE()` function

Answer (score 0):

Easy you just need to use the STR_TO_DATE MySQL function to convert your varchar to date:

```
$count=mysql_query("SELECT u.fname, u.lname, u.profile_pic, u.uid, u.bday, f.uid, f.friend_id, f.status FROM friend_list f, users_profile u WHERE f.uid = '$id' AND f.status = '1' AND u.uid = f.friend_id AND STR_TO_DATE(u.bday, '%m-%d-%Y')=DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE().'%m-%d-%Y') ");
```

But I strongly recommend you change the bday column to date type.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
date_format(your_friend_birthdate,'%Y-%m-%d')=date_format(now(),'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Full Query :-

```
    SELECT u.fname, u.lname, u.profile_pic, u.uid, u.bday, f.uid, f.friend_id, f.status FROM 
friend_list f, users_profile u WHERE f.uid = '$id' AND f.status = '1' AND u.uid = f.friend_id 
and month(u.bday)=month(now()) and date(u.bday)=date(now());
```

or

```
SELECT u.fname, u.lname, u.profile_pic, u.uid, u.bday, f.uid, f.friend_id, f.status FROM 
    friend_list f, users_profile u WHERE f.uid = '$id' AND f.status = '1' AND u.uid = f.friend_id 
    and month(u.bday)=month(now()) and day(u.bday)=day(now());
```

Comment: i only want to match the month and date not the year any way for that as year can't be same as friend cant be born in this year

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.fname, u.lname, u.profile_pic, u.uid, u.bday, f.uid, f.friend_id, f.status FROM 
friend_list f, users_profile u WHERE f.uid = '$id' AND f.status = '1' AND u.uid = f.friend_id 
and CAST(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(u.bday,7,11),'/',SUBSTRING( u.bday,1,2 ),'/',SUBSTRING(u.bday,4,2 )) AS DATE) = date_format(now(),'%Y-%m-%d');
```

Comment: Always use code formatting when adding code to post. It makes answer more readable. :D